# Mapping left Ctrl + right Ctrl to switch-windows

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'd like to add <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right Ctrl</kbd> to the switch-windows keybinding. Is there a way to distinguish between the <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>right Ctrl</kbd> keys when typing that command? Maybe something like:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab','<LControl><RControl>']"
```

However, that command doesn't work. I was wondering if there are actually key names specifically for the <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd> and the <kbd>right Ctrl</kbd> keys.

If you're curious why I'd want to do this, I have a Kinesis keyboard, and its default layout makes one stretch their left hand to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

- Edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`

  ```
  sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
  ```
- Remove `Control_R` from `Control` binding.Put `//` to comment original line and make new one with `Control_L` only:

  ```
  //modifier_map Control{ Control_L, Control_R };
  modifier_map Control{ Control_L };
  ```
- Then use System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Navigation to set it.

Comment: This may work, but it changes a fundamental key mapping for the entire system, which may have unwanted side effects. My answer works around this downside, PTAL.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Kinesis Advantage 2, and using Ubuntu. I opted to used `<Left ControL>+<Right Control>` for cycling to the next input method, since the default `<Super>+Space` isn't comfortable with this keyboard.

The easiest way to change it and make it persistent IMOHO is to use the `dconf-editor` tool which you can run from terminal. If you don't have it installed, just `sudo apt install dconf-editor` and then run it.

From there, search for your action's keybinding, in your case `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-windows` and in mine `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-input-source`. Once you're there, tick off the `Use default value` toggle and then you can type in this keybinding and hit apply so that the change takes effect: `['<Control>Control_R', '<Control>Control_L']`

**Variation:**

If you want some more control, you can use `['<Control>Control_R']` to keybind `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-applications` and `['<Control>Control_L']` to keybind `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-applications-backward` for bi-directional control with only those two keys.

**Explanation:**

Using both controls is a bit tricky, because if you try to use `['<Control_L><Control_R>']`, which was my first guess, it does nothing.

From my understanding after trial and error, the reason is this:

1. `<Control>` is captured as a modifier key press for any of the two control keys, but `Control` isn't captured as a regular key press for either of them.
2. On the flip side `<Control_L>` and `<Control_R>` are not captured as modifier key presses, but `Control_L` and `Control_R` are captured as regular key presses.

So, using the keybinding `['<Control>Control_R']` captures the combination when the left control if pressed first, followed by a press of the right control key while the left one is still pressed. Using the keybinding `['<Control>Control_L']` captures the reverse ordered combination. Combining the two, you can press both without caring what order they were pressed in.